# No boot or resume on battery

Tags: boot, battery, resume

Ubuntu 15.04, Lenovo G70/70 with Nvivia Geforce, Intel Core i3.

The laptop will not boot or resume on battery (100%). For a split second, the leds flicker -that's all.

Otherwise, Ubuntu works fine, but I need for it to boot where I cannot plug it in.

Please, do not assume I know a lot about command lines etc. "Handholding requested"

Comment: Tried several distros with the same result. Also changing to the Nvidia driver did not help.

Comment: Can you boot you system and then remove the power and continue on battery?? What is the remaining charge of your battery (Wh that it has now vs Wh that it should have by design. You can use "power statistics" for this.) It sounds kinda like a problem I had where I couldn't boot on battery because the smart check resulted in an error and the bios didn't allow booting with power check fails. The error was the result of a large discrepancy between the remaining maximum charge and the maximum charge that is "should have". I (temporarily) fixed this with a bios update but I don't recommend that(!!)

Comment: If that is the problem you're better of buying a new battery

Comment: After the boot I can continue using the battery. After the boot the battery still holds 99%. You gave me an idea: I probably can stop SMART. I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Good job on trying different distros. Since you have and get the same results and with what you said about the LED's flickering - I presume you have a battery issue instead of an OS issue.

The fix may be as simple as simple as charging the battery all the way, then removing and reconnecting firmly. Strange as it sounds, I've read from lenovo to not remove the battery when it's not fully charged, don't know what thats about.

If that doesn't work, Id say go to their [support page](https://support.lenovo.com) or call their helpdesk.

Good luck!

PS: how did you install Ubuntu on the laptop? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately removing the battery did not help.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu using a live dvd. The laptop was not on battery power then.

Comment: Bios says nothing about Smart. I tried the 'compatible mode' for the hd - no change. Tomorrow the laptop goes back to the shop because I will not touch the bios myself